# como poner el panel de lectura en un proyecto

Tags: vb.net

como todos sabemos windows tiene un panel de lectura o de vista previa para ver el contenido de un archivo, me pidieron un programa que abra archivos XML pero que se puedan visualizar utilizando el panel de lectura de windows, ademas que al abrir el archivo podamos escribir un mensaje y que tambien se vea el mensaje agregado en el visualizador de windows

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! De que panel estas hablando?